# Transaction Controller Usage in Jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter

I know that transaction controller is uage to logically group multiple samplers and it generate a sampler of itself. However I have a question on script performance optimization.

How advisable it is to use Transaction Controller if I have only Sampler in it? Does it impact the memory badly if I have 10s of those in the a thread group. Any link to best practice regarding the same will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Each element has its cost. Transaction Controller's cost is relatively low, it's just generating a virtual [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) plus adding metrics from each and every child to this virtual sampleresult plus sending the signal to the [Listeners](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) (if any)
2. There is no sense of having a Transaction Controller with only one child Sampler because it's response time, throughput, etc. will be absolutely the same as for its only child.
3. I wouldn't say that the number of Transaction Controllers in the Test Plan matter, it's more about the number of Samplers which are under the Transaction Controller (a little bit higher memory consumption, a little bit lower throughput), however if you [properly configure JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure/) you won't see any visible impact.

The only way to see the side-effect of having Transaction Controllers in the Test Plan is running your test with and without them under [profiler tool telemetry](https://www.baeldung.com/java-profilers)